# Can anyone tell me what this means?

Tags: translation, names

[image]

Sorry for bad drawing, I have been trying to find out for sometime without success.

Thank you

Comment: There are several tools that will try to recognize a character as you write it with your mouse. For example, try [MDBG](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php) and click on the paint brush next to the search box.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are 迪恩.  In Chinese they sounds like "Dean" in English? Is that a Chinese Name for someone?

Comment: Or maybe Deane - pretty much the same anyway